# Can I use snubber capacitors on smps output filter?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, filter

I'm working on a full bridge dc-dc converter and I got only snubber capacitors and no time for ordering new ones.

I got 350V-5.7A output, fsw is 30kHz

Capacitor: https://alconelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/IGBT-Snubber-Capacitors-Datasheet-KP-6.pdf.pdf

1uf-1200V rated, 6 in parallel

can I use this one for output filter capacitor?

Comment: *I'm working on* - repairing one maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it is a waste because snubber caps are prioritized to be rugged with good frequency response but sacrifice volumetric capacity and cost. They are physically large and expensive per capacitance.

Even six in parallel (which is a lot) only gives you 6uF which won't do much for 5.7A.